# Haproxy : my application login cookie is deleted by HaProxy !

Tags: haproxy

i want to use haproxy instead of microsoft load balancer.

My ASP application put a cookie after the user was logged in, i use this cookie to keep sessions on the backoffice.

But when i use Haproxy, my cookie doesn't appear in the list ! 
(i see the cookie set by the "cookie HaProxy insert nocache indirect" but not my own application cookie )

So, with Microsoft Load Balancer my cookie is ok :
http://img600.imageshack.us/i/cook2.png/

But when using HaProxy :
http://img821.imageshack.us/i/cook1.png/

Why Haproxy intercept my cookie and how i must configure it to let it pass ?
(it's not replace by the HaProxy cookie because if i juste use "rewrite" or "prefix" no one cookie appear)

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english !

This is my configuration file :

```
defaults
        log             global
        mode            http
        option          httplog
        option          dontlognull
        retries         3
        maxconn         8000
        contimeout      5000
        clitimeout      50000
        srvtimeout      50000

listen Backoffice 0.0.0.0:80
        mode http
        stats enable
        option httpchk http://mySite.com/index.asp
        option httpclose
        option forwardfor
        balance roundrobin
        cookie bstedg insert nocache indirect
        server  IIS 10.0.0.20:80 cookie iis check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 5 maxconn 800 weight 10 # disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to tell HAProxy anything about your cookies in this case. There is only one server in the backend and all you use cookies for in HAProxy is sticking to a backend server.